# 4Amps current sensor circuit with lm358

Tags: sensor, current-sensor

I have a 12v motor. I want to operate 12v 7amps relay with lm358 opamp.
when my motor is operate it gives 0.8 Amps, but when it get jammed then it consumes 4Amps, at that time I want to cut down my supply through relay.
I have make a circuit which cuts on 12v-13v but not on 4Amps. Please suggest me a real time circuit.

Comment: What happens next when 4 amps is detected?

Comment: SR latch for manual restart, maybe a 555 for a timed restart

Comment: Show your schematic, please.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hall effect current sensor [(example)](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8882) to detect the motor current. This device outputs a voltage proportional to the current it is sensing. Run this voltage into a comparator or ADC. The output of the comparator can drive a logic level FET that can cut off the voltage to your motor when it stalls. You will need to think about how you want the motor to come back on after a stall.

You could also sense current with a small shunt resistor in series with the motor in place of the hall effect sensor.